# Search an array for a text string in a separate array, return that text string (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of text values (column C below), they are of varying length. I have a separate array of text values (column A below). I want a formula that will look through the strings in Column C and return the word from Column A that it matches. If there are multiple matches (rare, probably won't happen), it will only return one.

Please see my example:

[image: Example]

Column D is the result I am looking for. As you can see, this will require some kind of fuzzy string matching. The word could appear anywhere in the cell. It doesn't need to be case sensitive. But I need it to pull that word out of the string as the result basically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use This:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$5)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,C2))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfection. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! Can you please explain how your answer works? The `AGGREGATE` function, in particular, has always been a challenge for me and I don't personally know anyone who uses it. Is your formula simply returning the first value in the `$A$2:$A$5` list that causes the division part of the formula to return a non-error value?

Answer (score 2):

One more, slightly simpler:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$100," * "&A2&" * ")>0,A2,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this formula `=INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(A:A,C2)))*1,0)))`. Enter it using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER since it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: 1. When using array formulas one should limit the sized of the referenced data to the data set to lessen the unneeded number of iterations.  Currently your formulas are doing over 5 million calculations.  2.  Your formula can be simplified to `=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,C2))*1,0))`  No need for SUMPRODUCT when using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thanks you, it was more a matter of speed that I left search with whole column referenced...but for 2. definitively more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This formula seems to be working for me:
(Please use Ctrl+Shift+Enter for the array formula to take effect)

`{=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(C2,"*"&$A$2:$A$5&"*"),0))}`

[Screenshot of Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMkYn.png)