# Search an Cell for a text string in a separate array, return that text string (Excel)

Tags: excel

I tried to use the formula from the post below

[Search an array for a text string in a separate array, return that text string (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674712/search-an-array-for-a-text-string-in-a-separate-array-return-that-text-string)

It looks like when I use it for my purpose it takes the first number of the array instead of the whole number i.e. for text string that has the number 2023 it will return 2 instead of 2023. Visual example below

Example

[image]

I need to return ticket number 2222 instead of 2 and only return 2 when the ticket number is indeed 2.  Please help, thak you.

I've tried the below

[image]

Comment: Your data is inconsistence. Doesn't make sense. Ticket number in column B and line memo doesn't match.

Comment: I wish I could have posted the entire file. Ticket numbers in columns B and C go on to 2665.  We have to think of columns E and F as a separate data set on a separate tab. Ticket number 2222 exists in columns B and C, but the formula just pulls ticket number 2. @hurun24hr